# My quicksort is sorting just marks instead of marks and student ids

Tags: c, quicksort

When I print the stu[] struct array in my main function it sorts only the marks but the ids stay the same. So for example stuid abc has mark 23 and def has mark 12, it swaps the mark so abc has 12 and def has 23. How do i make it so that the mark is swapped with the id.

```
struct student
{
    char id[20];
    int mark;
};

typedef struct student Student;
Student stu[5];

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int partition (Student stu[], int low, int high) 
{
    int pivot = stu[high].mark; 
    int i = (low - 1);

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        if (stu[j].mark < pivot)  
        {
            i++; 
            swap(&stu[i].mark, &stu[j].mark);
        }
    }
    swap(&stu[i + 1].mark, &stu[high].mark);
    return (i + 1);
}


void quickSort(Student stu[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partition(student, low, high); 
        quickSort(student, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(student, pi + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to swap the `Student`s, not the `mark`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is only swapping the key fields, but it needs to swap entire records.

Change the `swap` function to swap `Student`s instead of `int`s:

```
void swap(Student* a, Student* b)
{
    Student t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

Change the calls to `swap` to pass pointers to the `Student`s instead of pointers to the `Student.mark` values:

```
    swap(&stu[a], &stu[b]);
```

Comment: Ah i see. I tried that before and it didn't work because I forgot to change the pointers from student.mark. Thanks for the help!!